# "No module named gnomeapplet " error when trying to run battery indicator

Tags: 11.10, indicator

I'm trying to use battery-indicator on Oneiric 64bit. I downloaded sources, run "python setup.py install" in terminal but every time I try to start it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status", line 40, in <module>
import gnomeapplet
ImportError: No module named gnomeapplet
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImportError: No module named gnomeapplet`

In Gnome 2 - this python module would be installed by the package `python-gnomeapplet`.

However - this python module is not compatible with the Gnome 3 Panel - so the package has been dropped.

> python-gnomeapplet is no longer being developed as Python developers
>   need to use GObject Introspection instead of PyGTK to work with GTK3.

<sub>[source](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2011-August/012857.html)</sub>