# Gnome Shell panel timer / pomodoro

Tags: gnome-panel

I'm a fan of the [Pomodoro technique](http://pomodorotechnique.com); however, I'd like to have it integrated into my Ubuntu desktop. I found a timer applet that relies on the [discontinued](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65832/no-module-named-gnomeapplet-error-when-trying-to-run-battery-indicator) `python-gnomeapplet` package. So there are two acceptable answers to my question:

- How can I get a timer applet in my Gnome 3 panel? I'm using Cinnamon and I'd like to have the time remaining visible at all times.
- Is there a PPA or other source from which I could install `python-gnomeapplet`?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/158261/349837).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python-gnomeapplet is not supported anymore with Gnome 3.

Here is the alternative: https://launchpad.net/timer-applet

> **Timer applet**
>
> You can quickly set a timer and the applet will notify
> you when time is up. Add multiple Timer Applets to the panel to have
> different timers running simultaneously. Create presets for quick
> access to frequently-used times. Each applet remembers your last-used
> timer, even after you log out. The user interface follows the GNOME
> Human Interface Guidelines

You can download the package for 12.04 from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/timer-applet)

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Comment: Last release of that PPA was on 2011, but warns about an alternative: _If you are searching Timer Applet for Gnome 3, here you go [here](https://github.com/olebowle/gnome-shell-timer)_

Answer (score 0):

### [gnome-shell-pomodoro](http://gnomepomodoro.org/)

We have [this Pomodoro extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/53/pomodoro/): [Here the source code](https://github.com/codito/gnome-pomodoro/issues/256). Also with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-pomodoro
```

It have [this annoying unresolved bug](https://github.com/codito/gnome-pomodoro/issues/256) but could try *[workaround 2](https://github.com/codito/gnome-pomodoro/issues/256#issuecomment-392529723)*.

---

We can also use a free webapp like [**Tomato.es**](http://www.tomato.es/).